# How to distribute C# Windows Form App on other computers

Tags: c#, windows, publish

I've finished my first program and want to publish it such that it can be downloaded from a usb-drive and work on any Windows computer. I've folowed the steps and published my program as setup.exe file. I then copied the program to a usb to install it on the other computer but the program only works if the usb is plugged in, copying the program from the usb drive to the computer doesn't work.

Should I rather copy the contents of \Bin\Release folder?
any ideas ?

when I published the program it was in renew state I think, not debug mode if that changes anything. also as I followed the steps (right click on project solution and select publsh) after I chose an installation location I clicked finished, if you go to the next tab there are options of how the user will install the program either from website url, UNC file or cd-ROM. I don't know which option the program chose since the steps I followed didn't go to that step, I clicked finish on the previous step.

Comment: After publishing just make a zip file of the content inside the publish folder. Export the zip file to any computer and then extract and install the application. For this select the CD-ROM option.

Comment: thank a lot @AqibChattha. So satisfying to have written your own program XD

Answer (score -1):

Ah, make an installer? Either with tools from Microsoft (you do know about visual studio extensions, right? Has a marketplace where MS offers actually extensions themselves for free) or - WIX.

> Ive folowed the steps and published my program as setup.exe file. I then
> copied the program to a usb to install it on the other computer but
> the program only works if the usb is plugged in, copying the program
> from the usb drive to the computer doesn't work.

I hate to tell you, but you have not a setup if it EXECUTES from the USB. The file may be NAMED setup.exe, but it is NOT a setup.exe. That would not run the program but install it when you execute it.

I suggest you actually make an installer and not just rename the executable setup.exe and expect it to magically be an installer.

Btw., Capitals Are A Thing. You may hate them - but they make your textblob more readable.

Comment: Yes I've added the installer extension and created a new project as "Setup Project", everything works as it should now, Thanks Tom